# how to list data from 2 mysql datatable into html table

Tags: php, mysqli

in my mysql database there is 2 table named tblapps and tblapps2 . i have stored some of the data of an application in tblapps and rest of the data in tblapps2. 
in backend of my application, currenly all the data of tblapps is getting displayed but suddenly i have a requirement that i want one more column to be shown here from tblapps2 with column name  "country" and mysqli table column name "precountry" . and this is completely new for me, i am not getting anyway of doing this.

if any help it will be appreciated.

```
<div class="portlet-body flip-scroll">                                                      
                                <?php                                                           
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblapps order by id desc";                            
                                $result = $connect->query($sql);                            
                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                    echo "<table class='display' id='example'>
                                          <thead class='flip-content'>

                                            <tr>
                                                <th>ID</th>
                                                <th>App ID</th>
                                                <th>Full Name</th>
                                                <th>Journey Date</th>
                                                <th>App type</th>
                                                <th>Visa Type</th>
                                                <th>Fee</th>
                                                <th>Nationality</th>
                                                <th>Country</th>
                                                <th>Submit Date</th>
                                                <th>payment</th>
                                                <th>status</th>
                                            </tr>

                                            </thead>";                                                                                                               
                                      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                             echo"<tr>
                                                <td>" . $row["id"]. "</td>
                                                <td><a href=\"formdetails.php?app_id=".$row["app_id"]."\">". $row["app_id"]. "</a></td>
                                                <td>" . $row["firstname"]. "&nbsp;" . $row["lastname"]."</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["journeydate"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["appl_type"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["visatype"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["visa_fee"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["nationality"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["precountry"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["sdate"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["pay_status"]. "</td>
                                                <td>" . $row["appstatus"]. "</td>
                                                </tr>"; }
                                    echo "</table>";                                } else {    echo "0 results";}$connect->close();?>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please include the structure of your two tables.

Comment: Left JOIN Worked in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use SQL JOIN for matching values in both tables.

the implementation is depending on your tables structure

Comment: but whats happening is its showing all the data from left table 'tblapps' but if any application data is not there in tblapps2 , app_id for that application is not showing in html table.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblapps
                                       LEFT JOIN tblapps2
                                       ON tblapps.app_id=tblapps2.app_id
                                       ORDER BY tblapps.id desc";

Comment: could you give me more details about your tables structure? it will help me for solving the problem correctly